# How to hide sharepoint column fields on Display form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, jsom, js

I am using below code to hide a field on SharePoint display form but unfortunately its not working. Can someone please help me correct it, thanks in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
function init(){  
$('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr').hide();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the Jquery selector for the column needs to be hidden in display form  like below:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".ms-standardheader:contains('Resubmit for Approval')").closest("tr").hide();

    });
    </script>
```

Original:

[image]

Column hiddden:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry. I tried the above code you provided but its not working.

Comment: What is you SharePoint version ? Above tested in SharePoint 2013 On-Premise.

Comment: I am using SharePoint online

Comment: Updated the code, please check, tested in SPO.

Answer (score 2):

Normally your code would be in this order:

```
function init(){  
   $('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr').hide();
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');
```

Your problem is most likely due to waiting for other things:

- The jQuery library to load from the external CDN.
- Other SharePoint libraries.
- The creation of the elements in the form. (You did not say where you added your code.)

A more common way to delay the running of your code until after SharePoint content is loaded is to use a SharePoint array that behaves as a function loading queue.

```
function init(){  
   $('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr').hide();
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push( "init" );
```

Comment: I added script editor web part on display form and used this code:: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  
function init(){  
   $('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr').hide();
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("init");
</script>

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Did you get an error? Any error in the F12 browser tools? What do you see with: alert(  $('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr')  )

Comment: Mike, I received true when I ran the below code: function init(){  
$('nobr:contains("Resubmit for Approval")').closest('tr').hide();
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init,'sp.js');

Comment: Here is how field name appears on display form, as an anchor tag: <a name="SPBookmark_Resubmit_x0020_for_x0020_Approva"></a>