# Hide column display name on sharepoint list display form using jquery

Tags: sharepoint-server, jquery

How to hide the column display name in the sharepoint list display form using jquery.
I do not want to hide entire field. I want the control to be displayed but only the display name has to be hidden.

Kindly suggest any options.

Comment: I was just browsing your questions, could it be that nobody has ever satisfactorily answered a question you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using CSS only.

```
.ms-standardheader[id=columnInternalName] { display: none; }
```

Or hiding all the labels using CSS:

```
.ms-standardheader { display: none; }
```

Or by using jQuery (ID):

```
$(".ms-standardheader[id='columnInternalName']").hide();
```

Or hide all the labels in the list form

```
$(".ms-standardheader").hide();
```

Can be done with plain JS to:

```
var x = document.querySelector('.ms-standardheader[id="columnInternalName"]'); 
x.style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide fields in SharePoint list display form using jQuery, Navigate to DispForm.aspx->Edit page -> Insert a Script editor web part and paste the below codes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".ms-standardheader:contains('your column name')").hide();

    });
    </script>
```

Note: change 'your column name' to your column.

Hide list form field in SharePoint 2013 using jQuery for your reference:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/04/hide-sharepoint-list-form-field-using-jquery.html

[How to hide sharepoint column fields on Display form?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/245798/how-to-hide-sharepoint-column-fields-on-display-form)